# Resolve 'Out of memory' exception when calling DrawImage

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, system.drawing

About one percent of our users experience sudden crash while using our application. The logs show below exception, the only thing in common that I've seen so far is that, they all have XP SP3.

Thanks in advance

```
Out of memory.

   at System.Drawing.Graphics.CheckErrorStatus(Int32 status)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Rectangle destRect, Int32 srcX, Int32 srcY, Int32 srcWidth, Int32 srcHeight, GraphicsUnit srcUnit, ImageAttributes imageAttrs, DrawImageAbort callback, IntPtr callbackData)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Rectangle destRect, Int32 srcX, Int32 srcY, Int32 srcWidth, Int32 srcHeight, GraphicsUnit srcUnit, ImageAttributes imageAttr, DrawImageAbort callback)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Rectangle destRect, Int32 srcX, Int32 srcY, Int32 srcWidth, Int32 srcHeight, GraphicsUnit srcUnit, ImageAttributes imageAttr)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.DrawBackgroundImage(Graphics g, Image backgroundImage, Color backColor, ImageLayout backgroundImageLayout, Rectangle bounds, Rectangle clipRect, Point scrollOffset, RightToLeft rightToLeft)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e, Rectangle rectangle, Color backColor, Point scrollOffset)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e, Rectangle rectangle)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintTransparentBackground(PaintEventArgs e, Rectangle rectangle, Region transparentRegion)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e, Rectangle rectangle, Color backColor, Point scrollOffset)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e, Rectangle rectangle)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintTransparentBackground(PaintEventArgs e, Rectangle rectangle, Region transparentRegion)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e, Rectangle rectangle, Color backColor, Point scrollOffset)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e, Rectangle rectangle)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer, Boolean disposeEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Operation System Information
----------------------------
Name = Windows XP
Edition = Home
Service Pack = Service Pack 3
Version = 5.1.2600.196608
Bits = 32
```

Comment: Is it a very large image being drawn that would legitimately cause an out-of-memory exception?

Comment: @Jacob - hmm, we have one place where we take a screenshot of users desktop and display it to him. Now lets say he has 1920x1080x32 bit resolution it means that 8mb of memory is needed, right ? Is 8 mb too much to expect ?

Comment: That depends on how much memory has already been taken before this 8-MB.

Comment: @Lex Li - we don't have any significant memory allocation besides that particular scenario.

Comment: Some actual source code could help see what is going on.

Comment: @Joel - here is some code http://pastebin.com/ZD4M2SAJ

Comment: Which version of the .NET framework are you using?  I believe there was a bug in .NET 3.0 under Windows XP that was fixed with a service pack.

Comment: I bet the "Out of memory" error is a red herring. It's probably just getting some generic error and assuming that it's due to low memory. Whatever problem you're having, it's not because you're out of memory.

Comment: @Jacob - we're using .net 3.5

Comment: Gabe - maybe you're right, is there a way to retrieve more info from the exception ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe the problem is that GDI+ doesn't have detailed error codes, so .Net just translates the error to "Out of memory".

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure you've figured this out by now, but in case you haven't we hit the same issue. It's a bug in GDI+ and this works as a workaround. Unfortunately I don't know **why** but with these sorts of issues I tend to care more that it's fixed and less why it's fixed. ;)

```
image = image.GetThumbnailImage(image.Width, image.Height, null, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Apparently that call adjusts the PixelFormat and puts the image in a format that the imagelist's usage of DrawImage can handle.

From:
https://siderite.dev/blog/outofmemoryexception-in.html

Comment: actually I was unable to solve it, as it was happening once a month.. But I will definitely try this out, and mark it as solution if it won't happen again. Thank you

Comment: GetThumbnailImage uses the embedded exif data (or if it's missing bilinear scaling) Pretty low image quality. We need a better solution.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work in my case - GetThumbnailImage() now throws the OutOfMemoryException.  I am using DrawImage() with the ImageAttributes class variant.