# Graphics.DrawImage() - Throws out of memory exception

Tags: c#

I have some images that I need to do some crude re-size work on -- For the purpose of this example lets just say I need to increase the width and height of a given image by 4 pixels.
I am unsure why the call to Graphics.DrawImage() is throwing an OOM -- Any advice here would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filename = @"c:\testImage.png";

        // Load png from stream
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
        Image pngImage = Image.FromStream(fs);
        fs.Close();

        // super-hacky resize
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pngImage);
        g.DrawImage(pngImage, 0, 0, pngImage.Width + 4, pngImage.Height + 4); // <--- out of memory exception?!

        // save it out
        pngImage.Save(filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you draw a larger image into the `Graphics` object that is based on the original image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Graphics surface is only big enough for the original-sized image.  You need to create a new image of the correct size and use it as the source of your Graphics object.

```
Image newImage = new Bitmap(pngImage.Width + 4, pngImage.Height+4);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
```

Comment: Can you explain the +4?

Comment: @Pangamma the question asked about increasing an image's width and height by 4 pixels, hence +4.

Comment: Ahhhh wow. Ahaha. @Jlew Yes, that would be why. Thanks.Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem. However fixing the size of the output Graphics did not solve my problem. I realized that I tried to use a very high quality for the drawing the image which was consuming too much memory when I use the code on a lot of images.

```
g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
```

after commenting these lines out the code worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

That likely will not accomplish what you'd like to do seeing as how the image is the same size as the one specified by `FromImage`, instead you can use the `Bitmap` class:

```
using (var bmp = new Bitmap(fileName))
{
    using (var output = new Bitmap(
        bmp.Width + 4, bmp.Height + 4, bmp.PixelFormat))
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(output))
    {
        g.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0, output.Width, output.Height);

        output.Save(outFileName, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seriously, what's with the +4 thing?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this fix?

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filename = @"c:\testImage.png";

            // Load png from stream
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
            Image pngImage = Image.FromStream(fs);
            fs.Close();

            // super-hacky resize
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pngImage);
            pngImage = pngImage.GetThumbnailImage(image.Width, image.Height, null, IntPtr.Zero);
            g.DrawImage(pngImage, 0, 0, pngImage.Width + 4, pngImage.Height + 4); // <--- out of memory exception?!

            // save it out
            pngImage.Save(filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
```

Inspired by this question: [Help to resolve 'Out of memory' exception when calling DrawImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288204/help-to-resolve-out-of-memory-exception-when-calling-drawimage)